# Nodejs outof memory when reading big file

Tags: node.js, file-read

I have the following code to stream a file:

```
const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
 input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
 });
lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
   console.log(line);
   LineEntity.create({line: "some data"});//write some data to db
});
```

when executing the above code, I'm getting out of memory exception after 30-60 seconds.
when I execute the following, it runs perfectly without stopping...

```
//just to show that the problem is not with accessing the database
while(true){
   await LineEntity.create({line: "some data"});//and without await
}
```

when I execute the following, it runs perfect also.

```
lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
   console.log(line);
});
```

The problem is with the combination of the file reading and writing to the db.

Separately, they run perfect. together I'm getting out of memory exception

The error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[3903:0x47b4180]    42294 ms: Mark-sweep 2032.1 (2072.5) -> 2028.0 (2053.4) MB, 161.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 602.9 ms in 141 steps
 since start of marking, biggest step 6.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 838 ms) (average mu = 0.205, current mu =
0.172) finalize[3903:0x47b4180]    43117 ms: Mark-sweep 2034.1 (2053.4) -> 2024.0 (2067.7) MB, 805.3 / 0.0 ms  (average
mu = 0.120, current mu = 0.020) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x140dcd9]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x148be23]
Security context: 0x05a03e5408d1 <JSObject>
    2: save [0x1f10ab61b579] [/home/ron/work/hawking/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3950] [bytecode=0x22c0629957a1
offset=2439](this=0x02d3eccd2f21 <Model map = 0x2e79bc5fda69>,0x02d3eccd2ee9 <Object map = 0x4a68f580439>)
    3: /* anonymous */ [0x2b6513fc9bf9](this=0x2ccc7e8c2b21 <JSGlobal Object>,0x1460087004b1 <undefined>)...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa1a640 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1aa4c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb9a68e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb9aa09 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd57c85  [node]
 6: 0xd58316 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd64bd5 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd65a85 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8
::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd6853c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationO
rigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't while(true) an infinite loop?

Comment: @EAzevedo yes, this is an example that the database works out side of the reading file... that the problem is not with the database